# Sharepoint Asset Management

Tags: records-management

My Question is simple:

asset management system

> Does sharepoint have asset management integrated ?

We have 2,000 Computers,Printers and we looking for a new way to centralize the management.

We were wondering if it is possible to create an asset manager that we could integrate.

For example:

- Computer Asset
- Computer Prefix
- Computer Serial
- Computer Warranty

would be stored within a database and is searchable by criteria etc.

Can anyone help me find some information on the applications out there that I can use within sharepoint ?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance this can be achieved using a normal SharePoint custom list. If you want a site template for asset management, Microsoft created one for SharePoint 2007, and this has been [ported to SP2010](http://www.techsolutions.net/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/17/Fab-40-Templates-for-MOSS-2010.aspx) by a volunteer (look for Physical Asset Tracking).

I have seen demos that go a step further and use Visio Services and BCS to produce a nice pictorial diagram of servers and their status and so-on, which is probably more than you were looking for.

This [video showing Visio](http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/017863ab-01ee-4d50-9296-2e097ec6938e) might be of interest, although I think they just store a Visio diagram, rather than use a list.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really enough information to give you options.

SharePoint can be used as a standalone system, via Custom Lists, Forms, and Workflows (MS released a site basic site template for 2007 in their Fab40 collection).

You can integrate just about any other system that has an external API or that you can access the Database via the BDC / BCS. There are a number of standalone Asset Management systems (such as Remedy) that can be integrated with SharePoint, either with internal development or thru third party tools.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Microsoft System Center? the application is designed for what you are asking. And, I believe there could be an integration story between SP and System Center.

The following link is for manaing SP Server using Visio services and SCOM, but might get you going on the right path: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff872146.aspx

This is a screenshot of a real-time status of various SP farm components inside SharePoint.
[image]